# How to test binary compatibility automatically?

Tags: c++, automated-tests, static-analysis, backwards-compatibility, binary-compatibility

Can it be done before compiling, by comparing code? Is there any tools already doing this?

Answer (score 13):

[ABI Compliance Checker](https://github.com/lvc/abi-compliance-checker) — a tool for checking backward API/ABI compatibility of a C/C++ library:

```
abi-compliance-checker -lib NAME -old OLD.abidump -new NEW.abidump
```

*.abidump files are ABI dumps of OLD and NEW library versions generated by the [ABI Dumper](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper) tool.

[image]

[icheck](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/icheck) - C interface ABI/API checker:

```
icheck --canonify -o old_version -I/usr/include/foo/ bar.h
icheck --compare -o results.txt old_version new_version
```

[shlib-compat](https://github.com/glk/shlib-compat) - ABI compatibility checker that uses DWARF debug info:

```
python shlib-compat -vv OLD.so NEW.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall Purify had some functionality to verify compatibility between builds, [take a look here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/features/index.html).