# Tool to verify compatibility of a public APIs

Tags: c#, .net, api, backwards-compatibility

I work on a platform product which requires public compatibility between versions, so some code that was compiled against our previous build should be able to work against our new build without the need to recompile.

Is there a tool that would automated this verification, all I could find was [How to test binary compatibility automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970296/how-to-test-binary-compatibility-automaticaly) which seems to be for C++

Comment: Umh, I am not sure what do you mean by binary compatibility here. Are you talking about public interface compatibility or about something else?

Comment: Are you referring to COM to .NET binary compatibility or .NET to .NET binary compatibilty

Comment: updated the question to be more clear, i meant .NET to .NET public api compatibility

Comment: Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377855/tool-for-backwards-compatibility-for-c-net-api

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the [diff](http://apichange.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diff&referringTitle=Documentation) functionality of [ApiChange](http://apichange.codeplex.com/).

This utility takes a set of *old assemblies* and a set of *new assemblies* which are diffed for Api changes. The checks include :

- Added/removed types
- Added/removed fields, methods, events (and properties)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has released the tool that they use to check breaking changes in their releases; it's called [LibCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/using-reflection-to-list-version-to-version-assembly-changes-libcheck-one-of-the-best-tools-ever-kit-george).