# GCC ABI compatibility between versions 10 and 11

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, abi

Is there a way to check if GCC 10 and GCC 11 are compatible ?

Say I have a library built with GCC 10 and I use this lib to build my project with GCC 11.

Is it safe?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, all code you link together should always be compiled with the exact same compiler. C++ has no ABI stability guarantees.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794964

Comment: @JesperJuhl C++ might not have ABI guarantee but compiler and standard library vendors do https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html